# Slug not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am  try create slug with laravel on admin its work but on front-end view its work too except one problem, i have four article and work nice on admin but when on view front end its always open same article even-tough slug is different URL.

**Controller code**

```
public function singleArticle($slug){

    Article::where('slug', '=', $slug)->increment('viewed');




    $navi['country'] = Country::get();
    $navi['genre'] = Genre::get();


    $articles = Article::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(3)->get();
    $latest_movies = Movie::where('type', '=', 'movie')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(4)->get();
    $latest_tv = Movie::where('type', '=', 'tv')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(4)->get();
    $most_viewed_movies = Movie::where('type', '=', 'movie')->orderBy('viewed','desc')->limit(3)->get();
    $most_viewed_tv = Movie::where('type', '=', 'tv')->orderBy('viewed','desc')->limit(4)->get();

    $most_viewed_article = Article::orderBy('created_at','desc')->orderBy('viewed','desc')->limit(4)->get();



    $article = Article::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

and for view front end

```
 @if(count($articles) > 0)
            <div class="articles_list">
                @foreach($articles as $article)
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="article_item row">
                        <div class="article_info">
                            @if($article->thumb)
                            <a href="{{route('articles.single',$article->slug)}}"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url(Image::url($article->thumb,350,200,array('crop'))) }}" alt="{{$article->title}}">
                            @else
                            {{-- <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url(Image::url($article->thumb,250,250,array('crop'))) }}" alt="{{$article->title}}"> --}}
                            @endif
                            <div class="artice_title"><h3>{{$article->title}}</h3></div>
                            <div class="article_time">                                
                            <span class="author">By Admin</span>
                            <span class="cateogry">Category</span>
                            <span class="time">{{date('F d, Y', strtotime($article->created_at))}} </a></span></div>
                            <!--<div class="article_descr">
                                <?php echo  mb_substr($article->content, 0, 200) . ' ...'; ?>
                            </div>
                        <a class="btn btn-default read_more" href="{{route('articles.single',$article->id)}}">Read more</a> -->
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
                {{$articles->links()}}
            </div>
        @else
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Nothing found in there
        </div>
        @endif
```

**For routing below code :**

```
    // Category
Route::get('category/{slug}', ['as' => 'category.index', 'uses' => 'CommonController@categoryIndex']);

// Articles
Route::get('articles', ['as' => 'articles.index', 'uses' => 'CommonController@articleIndex']);

// Specific article
Route::get('articles/{slug}', ['as' => 'articles.single', 'uses' => 'CommonController@singleArticle']);
```

thanks before.

Comment: code formatting is important things always do it while ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just issue of naming convention.Please choose different names for variables.

1. `@foreach($articles as **$article**).` It is in your view which have $article variable.

   2. `**$article** = Article::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();` It is in your controller. so it is just because of conflict.